# Getting an 'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ' error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to creata a dynamic drop down select menu. I'm getting an unknown provider error relating to a function I'm using to create a date range. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >
  <li>
    <select id="makeSuperCategory" data-role="listview" ng-options="catagory as catagory.text for catagory in catagories.cast " ng-model="itemsuper" ng-change="changeData()">
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>       
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li>
    <select data-role="listview" ng-options="type as type.text for type in types.cast " ng-model="item1" ng-change="update()">

    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Factories

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory('catagories',function(){
  var makes = {};
  makes.cast = [
  {
    value: "acura",
    text: "Acura"
  },
  {
    value: "audi",
    text: "Audi"
  },
  {
    value: "geo",
    text: "Geo"
  },
  {
    value: "hummer",
    text: "Hummer"
  },
  ];
  return makes;
});

myApp.factory('acura',function( production_range,makesProductionEnded, makesInProduction){

var endedProductionObject = makesProductionEnded.filter(function( obj)               {
    return obj.make === this;
});

$scope.acura ={};
$scope.start = 1986 <!-- date Honda began production of the Acura product line -->

<!-- Set the most recent year option if still in production according to current month and model year change over October  -->
$scope.setEnd = function(){  
  if($inArray(this, makesInProduction) > 0){
    if(new Date().getMonth() < 10){
      end = new Date().getFullYear();
    } else {
      end = new Date().getFullYear() + 1;
    }

<!-- Set most recent year option if no longer in production according to year property value of object that matches this make in the endedProductionObject array  -->       
} else {
    end = endedProductionObject.year;                                                      
}
    return end;
}

$scope.acura.cast = [];
angular.foreach(years, function(value, year){
    acura.cast.push(acura[year] = value);
  });
  return acura;
});

myApp.factory('audi',function(){
  var audi = {};
  audi.cast = [
 <!--This will follow a similar pattern as acura once that is resolved -->
  ];
  return audi;
});

myApp.factory('geo',function(){
  var geo = {};
  geo.cast = [
 <!--This will follow a similar pattern as acura once that is resolved -->
  ];
  return geo;
});

myApp.factory('hummer',function(){
  var hummer = {};
  hummer.cast = [
<!--This will follow a similar pattern as acura once that is resolved -->
  ];
  return hummer;
});
```

Controller

```
myApp.controller('makeTypeCtrl',function($scope, acura, audi, geo,hummer, setNulls, catagories, production_range){

<!-- Push the model years into the years array according to the start and end dates  -->
  $scope.production_range = function(start, end){
    var years = [];

    for(var year = start; year <= end; year++){
        years.push(year);
    }
    return years;
  }

<!-- Defines the makes no longer in production and the date production ended for that make -->
$scope.makesProductionEnded = [{make:'eagle', year:1999}, {make:'geo', year:1997}]

<!-- Defines makes still in production -->
$scope.makesInProduction = ['acura', 'audi'];

$scope.catagories = catagories;
$scope.types = setNulls;
$scope.changeData = function() {        
  if($scope.itemsuper.text == "Acura") {
        $scope.types = acura;
    } else if($scope.itemsuper.text == "Audi") {
        $scope.types = audi;
    } else if($scope.itemsuper.text == "Geo") {
        $scope.types = geo;
    } else if($scope.itemsuper.text == "Hummer") {
        $scope.types = hummer;
    } else {
        $scope.types = setNulls;
    }   
  }
});
```

Here is a link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LujvM/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to inject `production_range` into your `acura` factory. But `production_range` is a variable on a controller's scope, not a factory or service that can be injected.

The second parameter to a factory should be a function that takes dependencies as its parameters. By dependencies I mean factories / services or anything else thats created from a provider, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers.
Read this as well: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di